# Python 2.7: Variable "is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested

I'm using [Physionet's data base](https://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM) for some tasks related to ECG signal analysis. I wanted to read .MAT files, extract the MLII readings on the file (located throughout row 1), adjust the signal to mV using "gain" and "base" (located in the .INFO filed also supplied by Physionet) and finally print the signal values and its period.

I wanted to write a script that could do all of those things to all the files in one folder. Before this, I wrote one in which I could do everythin mentioned above and it worked nicely.

But the script that would manage all the .mat and .info files in my folder is giving me problems with the variables. I tried using the 'global' command in the very beginning of my succession of IFs, but it kept sending a similar error message.

This is the code:

```
import os
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for file in os.listdir('C:blablablablabla\Multiple .mat files'):
    if file.endswith(".mat"):
        file_name=os.path.splitext(file)
        ext_txt=".txt"
        ext_info=".info"
        if file.endswith(".info"):
            f=open(file_name[0]+ext_info,'r')
            k=f.read()
            f.close()
            j=re.findall('\d+', k)
            Fs=j[9]
            gain=j[13]
            base=j[14]

        RawData=sio.loadmat(file)
        signalVectors=RawData['val']
        [a,b]=signalVectors.shape
        signalVectors_2=np.true_divide((signalVectors-gain),base)
        ecgSignal=signalVectors_2[1,1:]
        T=np.true_divide(np.linspace(1,b,num=b-1),Fs)
        txt_data=np.array([ecgSignal, T])
        txt_data=txt_data.T
        f=open(file_name[0]+ext_name,'w')
        np.savetxt(file_name[0]+ext_txt,txt_data,fmt=['%.8f','%.8f'])
        f.close()
```

The error message I get is:

```
> File "C:blablablablabla\Multiple .mat files\ecg_mat_multi.py", line 24, in <module>
    signalVectors_2=np.true_divide((signalVectors-gain),base)
NameError: name 'gain' is not defined
```

The problem comes with the variables 'gain', 'base' and 'Fs'. I tried to define them as global variables, but that didn't make a difference. Can you help me fix this error, please?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

EDIT 1: copied the error message below the script. 
EDIT 2: Changed the post title and erased additional questions.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is. What variable is not defined?

Comment: you can obtain the frequency looking for the string index of the words 'Sampling frequency' and then looking the corresponding characters after i.e.:
`index = your_string.index('Sampling frequency:')`
`frequency = your_string[(index+20): (index+23)]`

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry about that Daniel. I updated the question with the error message I get.

Comment: If this `if file.endswith(".info")` evaluates to `False` your names like `gain`, `base`, etc. are undefined because they will only be initialized if that expression evaluates to `True`, in some cases then your program attempts to process a file that does not meet that criteria.

Comment: @Jalo yes, I thought about an approach like that but I took the long and complicated way (measuring the lenght of the whole string, then just index in the range where the frequency came). You simplified that.

Comment: Don't ask 3 questions at once. Focus on one problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry about that! Should I edit the post and leave just one question?

Comment: I would recommend that. For one thing, when you solve one problem, the solution to that problem often allows you to solve other ones on your own. Why not digest one answer before asking more questions?

Comment: The error you are getting is because gain has not previously been defined. The reason is because the 'if' condition is never True. Thus, `file.endswith(".info")` is always False

Comment: @AquilesPáez Actually, you have an indentation error. I think that you should unindent once the second 'if' block. You are asking if the file ends at the same time with .mat and with .info

Comment: @JohnColeman you're right, will follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Jalo you're right. I did that, first I readed everything I needed from the .info file and store it in 3 variables. Then I began another if statement with the same indentation as the 1st IF. Now the error message is: 
"signalVectors_2=np.true_divide((signalVectors-gain),base)
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S6') dtype('S6') dtype('S6')"

Comment: How many ```.info``` files are in a directory?

Comment: @wwii the amount of .info and .mat files is undefined (though there's 1 .info file per .mat file with the same name), that's why I wanted to write something that will read everything on a folder despite the amount of files in it.

Comment: how are the ```.mat``` and ```.info``` files related - do they share the same name - like data1.info and data1.mat??

Comment: @wwii yes, they have the same names, the difference comes with the extension of the file. Like 100m.mat, 100m.info, 101m.mat, 101m.info and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two loops and extract the *info* before processing the data files

```
for filepath in os.listdir('C:blablablablabla\Multiple .mat files'):
    if filepath.endswith(".info"):
        Fs, gain, base = get_info(filepath)
        break
for file in os.listdir('C:blablablablabla\Multiple .mat files'):
    if file.endswith(".mat"):
        file_name=os.path.splitext(file)
        ...
        RawData=sio.loadmat(file)
        signalVectors=RawData['val']
        ...
```

---

I was working off your first edit so I'll include this even though the question has been *streamlined*

```
# foo.info
Source: record mitdb/100 Start: [00:00:10.000]
val has 2 rows (signals) and 3600 columns (samples/signal)
Duration: 0:10
Sampling frequency: 360 Hz Sampling interval: 0.002777777778 sec
Row Signal  Gain    Base    Units
1   MLII    200 1024    mV
2   V5  200 1024    mV

To convert from raw units to the physical units shown
above, subtract 'base' and divide by 'gain'.
```

I would also write a function that returns the info you want. Using a function to extract the info makes the code in your *loop* more readable and it makes it easier to test the extraction.

Since the file is well structured, you could probably iterate over the lines and extract the info by counting lines and using `str.split` and slices.

This function uses regex patterns to extract the info:

```
# regex patterns
hz_pattern = r'frequency: (\d+) Hz'
mlii_pattern = r'MLII\t(\d+)\t(\d+)'

def get_info(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        info = f.read()
    match = re.search(hz_pattern, info)
    Fs = match.group(1)
    match = re.search(mlii_pattern, info)
    gain, base = match.groups()
    return map(int, (Fs, gain, base))
```

---

If there are multiple .info and .mat files in a directory, you want to ensure you extract the correct info for the data.  Since the .info file has the same name as the .mat file that it *belongs* to, sort the directory list by name then group by name -this will ensure you are operating on the two files that are related to each other.

```
import itertools
def name(filename):
    name, extension = filename.split('.')
    return name

files = os.listdir('C:blablablablabla\Multiple .mat files')
files.sort(key = name)
for fname, _ in itertools.groupby(files, key = name):
    fname_info = name + '.info'
    fname_data = name + '.mat'
    Fs, gain, base = get_info(fname_info)
    # process datafile
```

Comment: This is great. Specially for the function reading the .info file. Physionet offers a Matlab script that scans strings in a similar way, like you're doing here. I wanted to do that myself, but I couldn't. This really helped me out. I barely have a couple of days doing things in Python and this task has been useful to clear doubts and make new questions. 

thanks a lot!